# What's the need of setting SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken) explicitly?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to get my head around spring security, reading spring security tutorials I've come across this below piece of code.
In `doFilterInternal` method it checks whether the Authorization token is set and it starts with Bearer token  if not then it directly calls `filterChain.doFilter()` method. Incase Authorization token is set it just explicitly add authorization token to security context and then calls `filterChain.doFilter()`. what's the need for this ? why do we set authenticationtoken to `SecurityContext` explicitly?

code

```
package com.betterjavacode.SpringAppCache;


import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;

import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;

import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;


import javax.servlet.FilterChain;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class AuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter

{

    public AuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
    {

        super(authenticationManager);

    }


    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)

            throws IOException, ServletException

    {

        String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if(header == null || !header.startsWith("Bearer"))

        {

            filterChain.doFilter(request,response);

            return;

        }


        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = getAuthentication(request);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);

        filterChain.doFilter(request,response);

    }


    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request)

    {

        String token = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if(token != null)

        {

            String user = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey("SecretKeyToGenJWTs".getBytes())

                    .parseClaimsJws(token.replace("Bearer",""))

                    .getBody()

                    .getSubject();

            if(user != null)

            {

                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());

            }

            return null;

        }

        return null;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set the authentication to the `SecurityContext` by using `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication`, you literally set the authenticated principal (which, in computer security is just an entity that can be authenticated) to the context.

This is extremely useful, because your filter will be a 'centralized' authorizer. So, when your filter do the authorization, it can set the authenticated user (the principal) to the context, and then the rest of your application can access the authenticated user through the `SecurityContextHolder`.

This is useful in a lot of cases, when you need to access the 'logged' user information somewhere during the request lifecycle.